# How do I fix "StrictVersion instance has no attribute 'version'" in git review

Tags: git, gerrit, git-review

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/git-review", line 863, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/local/bin/git-review", line 796, in main
    needs_update = latest_is_newer()
  File "/usr/local/bin/git-review", line 147, in latest_is_newer
    if latest_version > StrictVersion(version):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/version.py", line 140, in __cmp__
    compare = cmp(self.version, other.version)
AttributeError: StrictVersion instance has no attribute 'version'
```

How do I fix git-review?

Answer (score 4):

This error happens when you pass a version of `None` to `StrictVersion` or `LooseVersion`.

For Git Review, this happens because of an invalid file causing `None` to be passed into `StrictVersion` as mentioned in Matthew Flaschen's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the file:

```
~/.config/git-review/latest-version
```

This is caused by an empty or invalid file at that location (it is used for recommending updates when needed).  See [Launchpad #1098873](https://bugs.launchpad.net/git-review/+bug/1098873)

If the file is removed, it will automatically be regenerated.