# AttributeError: StrictVersion instance has no attribute 'version' with missing git-review file

Tags: python, git

I'm running a script on a legacy build system, and I'm getting the error:

> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/version.py", line 140, in **cmp**
>        compare = cmp(self.version, other.version)
>   AttributeError: StrictVersion instance has no attribute 'version'

I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14293727/how-do-i-fix-strictversion-instance-has-no-attribute-version-in-git-review) which says to remove the file at

`~/.config/git-review/latest-version`

and it will be automatically generated. The problem is I have no file here, in fact I don't even have a directory at `~/.config/git-review`

How do I go about fixing this? Can the git-review file be (re)created in some way?

git version is 1.7.9.5

Comment: What's the script you're trying to run?

Comment: It is a custom Python build script. Turned out the git thing was a red herring, but the error message was the same. I've now answered my own question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be nothing to do with git, although the underlying problem was similar to the git issue. Digging through the Python build script I was running it was failing on the line:

`assert StrictVersion(strict_version) >= StrictVersion(strict_prev_version) or not verify_newer, '%s is not greater than %s' % (strict_version, strict_prev_version)`

This was failing as a previously failed build had removed a version number from a config file. Adding the old version number back fixed the error.